# Open a window on windows server in a user desktop from the SYSTEM level cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, process, system

I came across an issue that I'm not entirely sure it is even possible.
I want to start a process (chrome browser for ex.) on a user desktop using a system level command prompt or powershell.

I tried many imitations such as runAs and -Credentials but they only open the process in the background "as" the user, not on the user's desktop. I want to actually RDP to the user's profile and see the browser open.

I'm aware there are risks of using system. This question is mostly on how to start a process on a specific user desktop rather than just appearing on task manager.

**Edit to clarify the issue:** 
I'm using windows server which has several of users, all of them are users that i have their name and password.
On that server, i have a process running under SYSTEM which i need it to open a process with a UI (a browser for ex.) in one of the other users's desktop.
The user's session is open and runnign and i can RDP/VNC/SSH/whatever to it and open whatever i want but that is not what i need. I want to RDP to that user after the browser was opened and see that it is already opened.

Comment: You can't do this from the command prompt or Powershell as far as I know.  You *can* do it from C or any other language with access to the Windows API.  The details depend a bit on whether you want the new process to run in the user's security context or as local system; in the former case, the relevant API functions are WTSQueryUserToken and CreateProcessAsUser.

Comment: The scenario is not clear to me. In the edit: "it" in the phrase "need it to open" is unclear. "session" is unclear in "user's session is open" (what kind of session?). "it' in "whatever to it" is unclear. The referent  in "open whatever" is unclear. "RDP to that user" is unclear (you don't RDP to a user you RDP to a terminal services session). And the final "it" is unclear.

Comment: thanks @HarryJohnston , the first case is what i need, i wanted to avoid writing a new code but i guess there's no escaping it :)
thanks again.